# Are there some words pronounced in English as in French?

Tags: pronunciation, french

Do you have an example, or several ones, of words that are pronounced the same (or very very close), in English and in French?

Comment: Are you asking about loan-words, such as *petits pois*?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Perce-Neige. Please provide a little more information about what you want: do the words have to mean the same, be spelt the same or just sound the same? Maybe it would help if you explained why you want these words.

Comment: Both. Loan and not loan. Is "Petit pois" pronounced like in French? pəti pwa?

Comment: Not meaning the same, not spelled the same, only close in the pronounciation. I'm only curious about pronounciations.

Comment: Please do a Google search on "French words commonly used in English." You'll find dozens to hundreds of examples scattered among several sites. (**Caution:** the Wikipedia list includes many words and phrases that I've never heard used in common American English speech, which may be indicative of our ignorance and parochialism.)

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for pronounciations. I'm curious to know if you know what you pronounce as French do.

Comment: I don't understand - You are looking for an English word, "dew", and a completely unrelated French word, "deux", spelled differently but pronounced the same?  Are you searching for cross-language puns?

Comment: In my admittedly limited experience, AmE tends to pronounce words from French the same as the French do, while BrE tends to Anglicize them, although I'm sure my British friends here will take offense at that generalization.

Comment: Any.. I don't think "deux" and "dew" are pronounced the same. There may be more chance with cognates/loan words.

Comment: @Mark I noticed that I think, and I wonder why.

Comment: Here is an interesting, casual list: http://www.thegoodlifefrance.com/common-french-words-also-common-in-english/ I recognize and use many (but not all) of the examples.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE  I still don't understand your question.  Are you looking for loan words and cognates, or not?  What are you trying to understand?  If you want the answers "Yes, some words in English are pronounced in French the same way" or "Yes, sometimes English-speakers put on a fake French accent when pronouncing French loan words", then please ask those.  At it is, your question is too vague.

Comment: "Il y a deux voitures" and "The ground is covered with dew": deux/dew are pronounced the same in AmE...

Comment: @John I searched "dew" is pronounced: [IPA] "dju" (so in French: it would be "diou". And "deux" is [IPA] "dø". So it's really different to me, because in "deux" there's no the "oo" sound. But for an American it may seems very alike maybe. Really interesting...

Comment: That IPA "dju" is BrE pronunciation (almost a dipthong), not usually seen in AmE.

Comment: Some people won't know how to pronounce *petits pois*, especially if they have not studied French at school. Applying English pronunciation rules will probably make it unrecognisable to French ears. My mother tried her best, but what came out was "pet-its poys" (sorry, I don't know IPA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are many words where we use the French pronunciation (although you might cringe at how we actually pronounce the words). For example, there are the "borrowed" words like *deja vu, denoument, blasé, laissez-faire* and so on, which are often recognizably from French.

But there are many other words which are part of common "parlance".  *Brunette* for example, pronounced much the same as the French do.  Also *clique, cliché,  concierge, cinema, malaise, melee, motif, mousse, panache, prairie, boutique, raconteur* ... anyway the list is very long.

But to take a few that are a good examples of what you are asking: "rapport" is pronounced with a silent "t", "rap-por" not "rap-port".  Similar is "debut", pronounced "de-bew" (or "day-bew") not "de-butt".  The American word "résumé" (a document describing your work and educational history, called a CV -- curriculum vitae -- in other places) is pronounced "re-zoo-may" not "ree-soom".

Even more fundamental is the way English pronounces the *"-tion"* suffix as *"-shun"*, in words like *action*, *friction*, *attention*, *nutrition* and so on.  If I understand correctly, most of these words come from the Old French, which is why some of the English words like *vacation* are now different in Modern French but still retain the French pronunciation.

Comment: @MarkHubbard for some people, yes.  Pronounciation can vary widely.  I personally pronounce it with a short "e" sound, but in other parts of the country (like the American South) they are more likely to pronounce it more like the long "a" sound.  And I think the British pronounce it with a short "e" and even more of an accent on the second syllable.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I removed my previous comment where I poked fun at Southerners, but you are right.  If I recall, folks in Louisiana don't always consider themselves fully part of the rest of the American South, though, especially where it comes to food.

Comment: Right! And in other ways as well. I think every other state in the union has a *Corpus Juris* based on English common law, while Louisiana has a "Civil Code" based on Napoleonic law (with further influence from the Spanish). It makes it difficult for lawyers from other states to pass the bar in Louisiana or to practice there, for instance.

Comment: Plus the wonderfully unique [Cajun accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAiHqOgEaEM)

Comment: Thank you, @PERCE-NEIGE and Andrew for a lively discussion!

Comment: Even if a word may, in principle, be phonetically the same, for example /ræpˈɔːr/, there will still be differences in the allophones used to represent a particular phoneme. For example, BrE and AmE r's are different, but they look pretty similar when compared to the guttural french r.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttural_R.

Comment: "Clique" is pronounced as in the French ("kleek") by British people, but not by Americans, who say "click".